# Velocity text input whith whitespaces

Tags: java, html, whitespace, velocity

I'd like to put String from my java class into text input. The problem is, when String contains whitespaces, everything after whitespace is gone. For example, if I'm trying to put the String `AP="new value"` into

```
<input type="text" id="AP" name="AP" class="text"   #if ( $AP ) value=$AP #end>
```

the value in input is just "new".
But when I'm using the same for plain text, like

```
<td>$AP</td>
```

everything goes fine.

Answer (score 1):

It appears you have missing quotes on your input text field. Wrap `$AP` with double quotes:-

```
<input type="text" id="AP" name="AP" class="text"   #if ( $AP ) value="$AP" #end>
```